# Picasso load images from URL in Strings

Tags: android, android-listview, picasso

i am developing a chat app that have functionality to take camera image while typing image & then send it to other user..

> what i have Done.

1. Take picture from camera when user click on button
2. Upload that picture to server & load image with picasso library & append it to editable text using **SpannableStringBuilder** (code is below)
3. After append it to my listview it will display like this `"<!>Hello World<!> (While <!> is my image separator)"`

Now i have a URL array of images that will be replace with `<!>` . 
i am trying to do it using picasso library but getting only one image replaced on appended list , i.e ( Hello World (-image is here) )

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(message.getMessage().contains("<!>")){

                    final String msg = message.getMessage();

                    Target target = new Target() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                            final Drawable drawImage = new BitmapDrawable( mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
                            addImageBetweenText(drawImage, holder.message, msg);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {

                        }
                    };

                        for(int k = 0; k < message.getURLS().size(); k++){
                            String url_str = message.getURLS().get(k).trim();
                                                        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url_str).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(target);
                    }
}
```

And here is my function for adding image between text.

```
private void addImageBetweenText(Drawable drawable, TextView tv, String msg) {
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),  drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        //for (int i = -1; (i = msg.indexOf("<!>", i + 1)) != -1; ) {

            int i = msg.indexOf("<!>");
            String st = msg.substring(i+3, msg.length());
            int selectionCursor = i;
            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(st);

            builder.insert(selectionCursor, ".");
            selectionCursor = i+".".length();
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable),selectionCursor - ".".length(), selectionCursor,    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(msg);
        //}

        //int selectionCursor = emojiconEditText.getSelectionStart();

    }
```

> My Problem ?

1. On my listview i only get the first image is replaced i.e `(<!> Hello World (image is here))`
2. is there any other best way to do this ? or any other library ?
3. i want to replace all `<!>` with my list of ArrayList of URLs in a string ..

Comment: *i only get the first image is replaced* **thats what this code do** ... addImageBetweenText is called only with one drawable ... you need to pass which text should be replaced with this specific image ... also you should store already downloaded image references ... maybe message class could have some containter which maps urls to drawable then you could iterate it check if drawable is no null and build Span ... that's what we call programming

Comment: @Selvin can you please tell me , where i am  wrong . ?